# How to find the differences between XML files in R

Tags: r, xml

I have two complex XML files and I want to find the differences between them.

What I need is to find:

- Tags that are present in only one of the two XML
- Values that are different from one another

I have tried `compareXMLDocs` from the `XML` package but it is not very satisfactory.

Example

```
XML1
<root>
  <first>name1</first>
  <second>id1</second>
  <third>
    <third.1>something</third.1>
    <third.2>something else</third.2>
  </third>
  <fifth>no differences</fifth>
</root>


XML2
<root>
  <second>id2</second>
  <third>
    <third.1>something2</third.1>
    <third.2>something else2</third.2>
  </third>
  <fourth>blahblah</fourth>
  <fifth>no differences</fifth>
</root>
```

So when I compare with `compareXMLDocs`, I have:

```
> compareXMLDocs(a, b)
$inA
first 
    1 

$inB
fourth 
     1 

$countDiffs
named integer(0)
```

I know that the `first` tag is used only in XML1 and that the `fourth` tag is only used in XML2. But I don’t know that the values in third.1 and third.2 are different for example. Which is what I’m looking for. I don’t understand what `countDiffs` does. Does not seem very useful here.

I also tried converting the XML in data frames but the output format is not very helpful. It gets worst for large XML file where the tree is deep.

The result I would expect for this example would be a data frame like this:

```
Path                  A                B
/root/first           name1            NA
/root/second          id1              id2
/root/third/third.1   something        something2
/root/third/third.2   something else   something else2
/fourth               NA               blahblah
```

Comment: _"Tags that are present in only one of the two XML"_ … by node position in tree? In general? _"Values that are different from one another"_ … at the same key tree node level in the same nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

read_xml("<root>
  <first>name1</first>
  <second>id1</second>
  <third>
    <third.1>something</third.1>
    <third.2>something else</third.2>
  </third>
  <fifth>no differences</fifth>
</root>
") -> d1

read_xml("
<root>
  <second>id2</second>
  <third>
    <third.1>something2</third.1>
    <third.2>something else2</third.2>
  </third>
  <fourth>blahblah</fourth>
  <fifth>no differences</fifth>
</root>
") -> d2
```

Make a quick helper function:

```
# NOTE: this will not handle attributes
as_path_df <- function(x) {
  as_list(x) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    as.list() %>%
    as_data_frame() %>%
    gather(key, val)
}
```

Here's what ^^ does:

```
(d1_p <- as_path_df(d1))
## # A tibble: 5 x 2
##             key            val
##           <chr>          <chr>
## 1         first          name1
## 2        second            id1
## 3 third.third.1      something
## 4 third.third.2 something else
## 5         fifth no differences

(d2_p <- as_path_df(d2))
## # A tibble: 5 x 2
##             key             val
##           <chr>           <chr>
## 1        second             id2
## 2 third.third.1      something2
## 3 third.third.2 something else2
## 4        fourth        blahblah
## 5         fifth  no differences
```

Keys?

```
setdiff(d1_p$key, d2_p$key)
## [1] "first"
```

Values?

```
rename(d1_p, d1_val=val) %>%
  left_join(rename(d2_p, d2_val=val)) %>%
  mutate(same = (d1_val == d2_val))
## # A tibble: 5 x 4
##             key         d1_val          d2_val   same
##           <chr>          <chr>           <chr>  <lgl>
## 1         first          name1            <NA>     NA
## 2        second            id1             id2  FALSE
## 3 third.third.1      something      something2  FALSE
## 4 third.third.2 something else something else2  FALSE
## 5         fifth no differences  no differences   TRUE
```

You *may* be able to use just `is.na()` on the various `_val` or `same` column for the key missing part, too. But `setdiff()` is super fast.